# Android Seek bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm just wondering if the seekbar changed in Android 2.1 . I tried to create one but it showing up as a green line with a circle on it instead of the usual yellow rectangle. If so, is there any other option to create a similar seekbar to control volume on 2.1? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`setThumb()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumb%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and [`setProgressDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgressDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) of SeekBar to customize the UI